Joining together 2 tables while joining one table twice with different filters
I have collected data in 2 SQL Server tables:
AREAS



area




a


b



SHIFTS



personal_id
date
shifttime
area




12
2012-01-10
early
a


13
2012-01-10
early
a


14
2012-01-10
late
a


15
2012-01-10
early
b



I want to join them together in a query like this:



area
date
early
late




a
2012-01-10
12
14


a
2012-01-10
13



b
2012-01-10
15




I have tried something like:
SELECT
    AREAS.area, early.date, early.personal_id as early, 
    late, personal_id as late
FROM 
    AREAS
LEFT JOIN 
    SHIFTS AS early ON AREAS.area = early.area
LEFT JOIN 
    SHIFTS AS late ON AREAS.area = late.area
WHERE
    early.shifttime = 'early' 
    AND late.shifttime = 'late' 
    AND date = '2012-01-10'

but that outputs:



area
date
early
late




a
2012-01-10
12
14


a
2012-01-10
13
14


b
2012-01-10
15




Is there any other way to join or do I have to save my data differently in SQL Server?

Putting a clause like early.shifttime = 'early' into the WHERE when you have a LEFT JOIN to early makes that JOIN an INNER JOIN; it's impossible for early.shifttime = 'early' to be true if no row in the table was found.

There are multiple personal_id under the same area, date & shift and you wanted to show it under different row. You can use row_number() to generate a running number for each of the personal_id.
row_number() over (partition by a.area, s.date, s.shifttime 
                       order by s.personal_id)

From there you can use the PIVOT query
select area, date, early, late
from   (
           select a.area, s.date, s.shifttime, s.personal_id,
                  rn = row_number() over (partition by a.area, s.date, s.shifttime 
                                              order by s.personal_id)
           from   AREAS a
                  left join SHIFTS s on a.area = s.area
       ) d
       pivot
       (
           max (personal_id)
           for shifttime in ([early], [late])
       ) p

or the conditional case expression way
select d.area, d.date, 
       early = max(case when shifttime = 'early' then personal_id end), 
       late  = max(case when shifttime = 'late'  then personal_id end)
from   (
           select a.area, s.date, s.shifttime, s.personal_id,
                  rn = row_number() over (partition by a.area, s.date, s.shifttime 
                                              order by s.personal_id)
           from   AREAS a
                  left join SHIFTS s on a.area = s.area
       ) d
group by d.area, d.date, rn


i honestly cant comprehend whats going on, but that is exactly what i want! Thank you very much!
